# Using Facebook Graph API to get HTML of posts

Tags: facebook

I would like to show the entire HTML of each of my Facebook posts. As is, when using the Graph API, selecting `posts` via `GET->/v.2.8/me?fields=id, name, posts` I get the following results, roughly.

```
{
  "id": "1111111111",
  "name": "My Company Name",
  "posts": {
    "data": [
      {
        "message": "Check out this picture",
        "created_time": "2017-01-30T18:54:00+0000",
        "id": "1111111_1111111"
      },
      {
        "story": "My Company updated their profile picture.",
        "created_time": "2017-01-30T15:08:00+0000",
        "id": "111111111_11111111"
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

In my message where it states `Check out this picture` I attached a photo. However, the api does not show it. It only gives me the text that I accompanied with that photo.

How might I get all the HTML of each of my Facebook posts?

Comment: You need to specify which fields you want otherwise you just get the default fields

Comment: I was hoping to get the entire post content. As is, the API only gives me the text `Check out this picture` while ignoring the photo that I have placed in that post. Adding `photos` to my `GET` request does not really rectify this.

Comment: The API only gives you the fields you ask for. story, created_time and id are the default fields. If you want more fields you have to ask for them